# Possible bug in volume of text required in question setup on main Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, edits, quality-filter

On the main Stack Overflow site over the last two days, I've seen at least 3 new questions where there has been a need to add a large block of unnecessary text to the question, in order to override a '*please add more details*' request by the editing software.

Yesterday I tried to edit a question where the phrase 'More Details' had been added more than 50 times. However when I deleted this large block of text the editing software wouldn't accept the reformatted question. The error message was something like "It seems as though your question is mostly code, please add more details"

Here is another example where the questioner has added two large paragraphs of `lorem ipsum` to overcome the same issue:

[Can you figure out why section 2 is going behind the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768805/can-you-figure-out-why-section-2-is-going-behind-the-video-thanks)

I haven't seen this occurring before two days ago

Comment: Keep in mind that it is september and that means a lot of schools / universities are starting, increasing the number of new users that need to find their way. If anything, it shows our editing guidance is sub-par and/or the reading willingness of those new recruits.

Comment: A useful point about new influx @rene _ will keep that in mind _ But when I tried to edit the 50+ 'More Details' I actually tried to reduce the number of repeats in steps but the editing software wouldn't accept anything less_ and the paragraphs of `lorem ipsum` are larger than what I'm used to reading in text written in other questions _ By the way I'm not insisting my observation should be acted on_ but thought it worth reporting o: )

Comment: One thing I noticed on the example post you linked: Code blocks need an blank/empty line before the **start** and after the  **end** of the code block. On top of that, if the post contains characters that are not letters / numbers and those characters are not contained in a sentence or code block you are most likely to trip the quality check.

Comment: @rene _ thanks for your help on this _ This will make things much easier when editing _ Pleased I asked now!

Comment: Please consider using periods, commas, semicolons, and other standard punctuation in your text. The underscores are quite distracting...